# Suppose that $f (x)$ is $O(g(x))$. Does it follow that $2^{f(x)}$ is $O(2^{g(x)})$?

Tags: asymptotics

Suppose that $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$. Does it follow that
[image] ?

First, I start from [image] for some $c$ is a real number. Then, I find [image]. But, if i start from [image], I just find [image].
I confused with that different form.

Comment: $3^x \neq O(2^x)$ (prove by definition) , so it is not hard to find $f(x)=O(x)$ but $2^{f(x)} \neq O(2^x)$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = x/2$ for $x\geq 0$. Then, $f(x) = 2g(x) = O(g(x))$, but you don't have $2^x = O(2^{x/2})$ (if $2^x \leq c 2^{x/2}$, then $x \leq \log(c) +x/2$, which is absurd). The answer to your question is no.